# Check pre-selected rows in a jQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, kohana-3

I have a jQuery DataTable below:

```
examinees_table = $('#examinees_table').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
            /*select*/      null,
            /*id*/          {"bVisible": false},
            /*name*/    null,
            /*course*/  null
        ]
    });
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<table id="examinees_table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Select</th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Full Name</th>
                                <th>Degree</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach($users as $user) {?>
                                <tr>
                                    <?php foreach ($examinees as $examinee) {?>
                                        <?php if($examinee->examinee_id == $user->id) {?>
                                            <td class="center"><?= Form::checkbox('is_examinee-'.$user->id, null, (bool) true, array('id' => $user->id)); ?></td>
                                        <?php } else {?>
                                            <td class="center"><?= Form::checkbox('is_examinee-'.$user->id, null, (bool) false, array('id' => $user->id)); ?></td>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    <td class="center"><?= $user->id; ?></td>
                                    <td class="center"><?= $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name; ?></td>
                                    <td class="center"><?= $user->courses->description; ?></td>
                                    <?php }?>
                                </tr>
                            <?php }?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

**What I want to do:**

I need to load all the registered users from my Users table and check each user in my datatable whose ID is in my Examinees table.

I am updating a list of examinees, so the user can remove(uncheck) existing examinees and add more examinees. I can get the checked rows before submitting the form, but I don't have a way to determine which of the existing examinees were unchecked so I could remove there ID in the Examinees table.

What could be a best approach for this? I don't feel that what I did in my HTML is the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to get my desired output, in my datatable I used the fnCreatedRow function to check each created row if it's in the EXISTING EXAMINEES array:

```
examinees_table = $('#examinees_table').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
            /*select*/      null,
            /*id*/          {"bVisible": false},
            /*name*/    null,
            /*course*/  null
        ],
        "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            var eID = $('#existing_examinees').val();
            if(eID === undefined) {
                return;
            }

            var eIDArray = eID.split('/');

            var deletedID = $('#removed_examinees').val();
            var deletedIDArray = deletedID.split('/');

            if(eIDArray.length > 0) {
                $.each(eIDArray, function(index, value) {
                    var id = $("input:checkbox", nRow).attr('id');                      
                    // alert('index: ' + index + ' ' + 'value: ' + value + ' ' + 'id: ' + id);
                    if(id == value) {
                        $("input:checkbox", nRow).prop('checked', true);
                    }
                });
            }
            $("input:checkbox", nRow).click(function() {
                var selected_id = $("input:checkbox", nRow).attr('id');
                var checked = $("input:checkbox", nRow).prop('checked');
                if(checked == false) {
                    var deleted_index = $.inArray(selected_id, eIDArray);
                    var inDeletedArr = $.inArray(eIDArray[deleted_index], deletedIDArray);
                    if(inDeletedArr < 0) {
                        if(deleted_index > -1) {
                            var removed = $('#removed_examinees').val();
                            if(removed == '') {
                                removed = eIDArray[deleted_index];
                            } else {
                                removed = removed + '/' + eIDArray[deleted_index];
                            }
                            $('#removed_examinees').val(removed);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I also added an onClick listener to add existing examinees that are unchecked which will be submitted to the server when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it:

1. Clear every examinee id from the database before adding the ones that come with the POST data.
2. Implode the POST id array, delete the ones `NOT IN (id1, id2, ...)` and add the new examinees.

PS. To avoid duplicate code move the examinee == user condition to the checked attr.

```
<?= Form::checkbox('is_examinee-'.$user->id, null, ($examinee->examinee_id == $user->id), array('id' => $user->id)); ?>
```

PPS. the examinee foreach seems weird, maybe you should do a subselect.